# How to dock an image in header using CSS Grid?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I am trying to keep the right-side image in my header docked to the right.  Perhaps I can use float, but I am trying to do this using CSS Grid.  Also, maybe there is a better implementation.

Eventually, I do want to put a menu/nav, body, and footer to this.  Are there any good CSS Grid-based templates out there that cover responsive, mobile-first design? The working jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cox/4cqpws2o/275/

Latest revision which includes bootstrap, and re-works the "section" elements to use divs with class="section" (needed after adding bootstrap):  https://jsfiddle.net/cox/4cqpws2o/578/

```css
article {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
      grid-auto-rows: 130px;
      grid-gap: 0px;
    }

section:nth-child(1) { grid-column: 1 / 4; grid-row: 1; }
section:nth-child(2) { grid-column: 2 / 5; grid-row: 1; z-index: 1; }
section:nth-child(3) { grid-column: 3 / 7; grid-row: 1; }

/*@media ( max-width: 500px ) {
   article { grid-template-columns: 100px; justify-content: center; }
   section:nth-child(1) { grid-row: 1 / 4; grid-column: 1; }
   section:nth-child(2) { grid-row: 3 / 5; grid-column: 1; }
   section:nth-child(3) { grid-row: 5 / 7; grid-column: 1; }
}*/

/* non-essential demo styles */
section:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: transparent;
  /*border: 2px solid red;*/
  justify-content: left;
}
section:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: transparent;
  /*border: 1px solid blue;*/
  justify-content: left;
}
section:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid orange;
  justify-content: right;
  min-height: 130px;
  width: 485px;
}
section {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center; /* default */
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
.header-title {
  background-image: url('https://res.cloudinary.com/adamcox/image/upload/v1557459731/header-test/TEST-SIGNx2.png');
  /*transform: scale(.5) translate(-50%, -50%);*/
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position-x: bottom;
  background-position-y: top;
  min-height: 28px;
  min-width: 330px;
}
.header-left {
  background-image: url('https://res.cloudinary.com/adamcox/image/upload/v1557459316/header-test/LEFTx2.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position-x: bottom;
  background-position-y: left;
  min-height: 130px;
  min-width: 166px;
}
.header {  
  background-image: url('https://res.cloudinary.com/adamcox/image/upload/v1557459316/header-test/BGPATTERNx2.jpg');
  z-index: -1;
  min-height: 130px;
  /*display: flex;*/
}
.header-right {
  background-image: url('https://res.cloudinary.com/adamcox/image/upload/v1557459316/header-test/RIGHTx2.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  min-height: 130px;
  min-width: 485px;
  background-position: right top;
}
```

```html
<article class="header">
  <section><span class="header-left">1</span></section>
  <section><span class="header-title"></span></section>
  <section><span class="header-right"></span></section>
</article>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are *overlapping* your grid item using the `grid-column` definitions, then using `justify-content: start` that overrides the default *stretch* of the columns across the grid cell and then using fixed widths for the `section` elements.

Instead, I'd suggest a 3-column grid with images in the right and left columns and the text in the middle:

```css
article {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 130px;
  background: url('https://res.cloudinary.com/adamcox/image/upload/v1557459316/header-test/BGPATTERNx2.jpg');
}

section:nth-child(1) {
  background: url('https://res.cloudinary.com/adamcox/image/upload/v1557459316/header-test/LEFTx2.jpg') no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

section:nth-child(2) {
  background: url('https://res.cloudinary.com/adamcox/image/upload/v1557459731/header-test/TEST-SIGNx2.png') no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
}

section:nth-child(3) {
  background: url('https://res.cloudinary.com/adamcox/image/upload/v1557459316/header-test/RIGHTx2.jpg') no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<article class="header">
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
</article>
```

---

Maybe even the grid layout is an *overkill* - you can use a background to include the whole header in one element (the below demo does it mobile-first by adjusting the `background-position` property):

```css
article {
  height: 130px;
  background: url('https://res.cloudinary.com/adamcox/image/upload/v1557459731/header-test/TEST-SIGNx2.png') no-repeat,
              url('https://res.cloudinary.com/adamcox/image/upload/v1557459316/header-test/LEFTx2.jpg') no-repeat, 
              url('https://res.cloudinary.com/adamcox/image/upload/v1557459316/header-test/RIGHTx2.jpg') no-repeat, 
              url('https://res.cloudinary.com/adamcox/image/upload/v1557459316/header-test/BGPATTERNx2.jpg');
  background-size: 33.33% auto, contain, contain, cover;
  background-position: center, left center, 250px, center;
}

/* for desktop */
@media only screen and (min-width: 900px) {
  article {
    background-position: center, left center, right, center;
  }
}
```

```html
<article></article>
```

Comment: Thank you @kukkuz.  I do like what your use of background, but I am looking specifically on how to right justify the far right div using CSS Grid.  I will review and revise question...

Comment: @AdamCox check this out: https://jsfiddle.net/c2bumas7/ there are slight changes in the html structure (along the lines of the CSS grid solution in my answer)... check it out and let me know, will the fiddle to the answer if its working fine :)

Comment: @AdamCox so how did it go? Does the above fiddle solve it?